# Reference For a PDE text that treats non homogenuous boundary conditions Rigorously

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, heat-equation

I am interested in reading a text or paper where elliptic and parabolic PDE's are discussed on bounded domains with non-homogeneous boundary conditions.  I haven't been able to find anything in the usual places (Evan's and some Finite Element books).  I would like to see proofs of stability/ contraction for parabolic PDE's with time varying boundary conditions.

Does anyone have a preference for me?  Thanks!